# Комментарии к полям таблицы/Вывод в коде

Tags: php, laravel

Имеется поле таблицы со следующей структурой:

```
ALTER TABLE `information` ADD `title` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL COMMENT 'Название записи';
```

Как вывести комментарий к полю таблицы "Название записи" в .php коде?

Comment: Комментарии не входят в стандарт ANSI SQL, поэтому нельзя рассчитывать на человеческое API (тем более - кросс-движковое) для их получения.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT column_comment
  FROM information_schema.columns
 WHERE table_name = 'my_tbl_name'
   AND table_schema = 'my_database'
   AND column_name like 'the_column'
```

Answer (score 0):

Хз как нативно сделать , но могу предположить что костыльнуть можно так :

```
SHOW CREATE TABLE `bd`.`table`;
```

Ну и в php тупо регуляркой выдернуть

```
preg_match_all("#COMMENT\s\'(.?*)\'#" , $subject , $res);
print_r($res);
```